# How to remove Pass Phrase from certificate or how to enter pass phrase by script not manually

Tags: apple-push-notifications, passphrase

I am using PyAPN API to send notification over ios device but certificate which i have that need pass phrase.
After Entering pass phrase it send notification to ios.
but when certificate created without pass phrase it give error

```
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Exception ssl.SSLError: SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure') in > ignored
```

or

```
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 336265225] _ssl.c:351: error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib
Exception ssl.SSLError: SSLError(336265225, '_ssl.c:351: error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib') in > ignored
```

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372128/iphone-push-notifications-passphrase-issue-pyapns) link to remove pass phrase. is there any way to write script in python which provide pass phrase auto.whenever it asked by certificate.
At which point i am making mistake.
please provide information.